# Qt application crash upon startup at MainWindow.Show() call

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, segmentation-fault, windows-10

I'm trying to find out the reason of the crash of my Qt application, the debug doesn't contain much information available hence the difficult to find the reason... after using breakpoints, the closest I found was the line the crash might be at `w.show()` call (the application's GUI frooze before any button or anything at all show up). My main function is exactly this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;

    // disable Window's maxminize button
    const Qt::WindowFlags flags = w.windowFlags() ^ Qt::WindowMaximizeButtonHint;
    w.setWindowFlags(flags);
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

when the line where `w.show()` is reached, the application starts (but not properly, the GUI frooze, as I mentioned before) and after several minutes I got a SEGFAULT and the debugger look like this:

[image]

How can I fix this? I'm on this has been days, trying to get the debugger give more information so that I can trace back the `SEGFAULT` reason but without the debugger information like this, I have no idea what to do.

My Qt version:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found solution!**

Hope it's useful to anyone with same issue:

In the debug messages I found out the crash was result from `GBIEH.dll` dll. Googling it I found it's related to internet banking (I guess when my application tried to use that dll the IB's application take this as a kind of attack hence the crash, my guess). I just removed the internet banking programa and the application worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to tackle such a problem, assuming you can't provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

- Strip the elements of MainWindow one by one, first from the constructor, and see what creates the crash
- If stripping elements from the constructor helps, then restore parts of it, and run the debugger to study what causes the freeze
- Keep in mind that freezing in GUI programs usually means the event loop is blocked. If you're calling `QApplication::processEvents()` anywhere, consider removing that.
- Finally, if everything fails, you're gonna have to go to a linux system, and recompile Qt in debug mode (debug + release never worked for me), and track the event loop and see, in code, what freezes your GUI.

The reason I'm recommending Linux is because gdb is great, and cdb is horrible at this. If you have VS enterprise, you could try its debugger too.

Good luck.

Comment: I've tried #1 already by putting a breakpoint in every line of the constructor, it reached end of constructor fine. So the error isn't there. #2: same as #1. #3 I don't call it anywhere on application startup. So I guess it excldue it too. #4 thanks for the tip, if I spent more time on this I'll try on linux. #5: I'll try right now attach to vs debugger. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The part of original code that has a problem (fixed) :

```
// disable Window's maximize button (use bitwise [and-not]&~ and not [xor]^)
const Qt::WindowFlags flags = w.windowFlags() &~ Qt::WindowMaximizeButtonHint;
w.setWindowFlags(flags);
```

or that same effect can be achieved by:

```
w.setWindowFlag(Qt::WindowMaximizeButtonHint, false);
```

Comment: Thanks for the fix. But `w.setWindowFlag()` give not found error. Which Qt version are you using?

Comment: I am on Qt 5.7 and 5.9 (maybe unrelated to your problem) on Mac and Linux. The line was not correct and not giving you what you want. I could not possibly know about GBIEH.dll somewhere in your system. For several years doing Qt apps on Windows never run in that and the code is quite simple with just one apparent error (though not leading to crash).